# Android Studio Layout - Horizontal centering in parent of two textviews that are next to each other on same line

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview

I have a beginners question about relative layouts and centering of two textviews in Android Studio. I have two textviews that are aligned on the same line and the right one is aligned "toEndOf" the left textview. Now how do I center them both horizontally in the parent so the line of text is centered left to right on the screen? See image.

[image]

With the given layout, "I Am" is nicely centered horizontally, but I want the both textviews taken together to be centered so that "I Am Poor" is centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern replacement for `RelativeLayout` is `ConstraintLayout`. In a ConstraintLayout, you can create what are called *chains* of views, and then define centering behavior for the entire chain.

Here's how you'd do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="short"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/large"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="very very very long"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/small"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The *chain* is formed by connecting both the start and the end of **both** views to each other and to the parent:

```
android:id="@+id/small"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/large"
```

```
android:id="@+id/large"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/small"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

You then also apply the `packed` style so that the views are positioned exactly next to each other, rather than spread out with space between them:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
```

In the end, this is the result:

[image]

Comment: The syntax for ConstraintLayout is definitely more complex than for RelativeLayout, but it is dramatically more powerful and generally all-around _better_. I'd recommend getting used to using it sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thank you Ben! I'll give this a try in the morning. And thank you for pointing out the more modern way of doing this type of layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would put them inside another layout (as linear with horizontal orientation) and then center that other layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="ONE"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="TWO"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```